# How to fix warning for Locale.canonicalIdentifier(from:)

Tags: ios, locale, foundation

I'm compiling an app for target iOS 14+

When using `Locale.canonicalLocaleIdentifier(from:)` the compiler shows a warning:

```
'canonicalLocaleIdentifier(from:)' is deprecated: renamed to 'identifier(_:from:)'`
```

But [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293476-canonicalidentifier) for this API states that it is only deprecated in iOS 16.

Furthermore `Locale.identifier(_:from:)` is [only available for iOS 16](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/4020220-identifier).

So how could I silence this warning?

Answer (score 0):

This one can simply be fixed by using `if #available`

```swift
if #available(iOS 16, *) {
    return Locale.identifier(.icu, from: <the ID>)
} else {
    return NSLocale.canonicalLocaleIdentifier(from: <the ID>)
}
```